# create own sort() function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create my own sort() function on an array in javascript. The function should expect the following string elements in the list `[0-9]*[A-Z][0-9]*[A-Z][0-9]*` That means first there are arbitrary number of numbers 0-9, then there is One letter, followed by arbitrary numbers 0-9, then One Letter and then finally arbitrary numbers 0-9. Now I want to sort this list, but I want to sort it backwards on the Letters Only. That means that for example `[xExCx,xQxEx,xSxEx,xSxFx]` will become after its sorted `[xSxFx,xSxEx,xQxEx,xExCx]` where again x is an arbitrary number of numbers 0-9. It will sort on the first letter (backwards) first and then the second letter. So that letter E comes before an A. Perhaps anyone of you brilliant guys could give me a push in the right direction, I have only gotten this far.

```
function sortList(listOfNames) {
   var sortedListOfNames=new Array();
   for (i = 0; i < listOfNames.length; i++) { 
   //Sort listOfNames
   }
}
```

Comment: So you want a reverse sort on only the letters in the string?  Do you want to completely ignore the values or quantity of numeric digits anywhere in the string?

Comment: Have you looked at the callback for `sort`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort If you can create a simple snippet of code that does your custom letter comparison, you can easily write a callback that sorts by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sorting logic already built into arrays and just apply a custom comparison function.  Assuming that your sort algorithm is to disregard all numeric digits in the string and just do a reverse sort on the alpha characters left in the string, you can supply a sort callback function to the `.sort()` built into the Array object like this:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.replace(/\d/g, "");
    b = b.replace(/\d/g, "");
    return b.localeCompare(a);        
});
```

This removes all the numeric digits from the two strings, then does a string comparison of the two and returns that result.  The `.sort()` method then performs a sort based on that comparison algorithm.  You can reverse the order of the sort by simply swapping `a` and `b` in the `localeCompare()` statement using either `b.localeCompare(a)` or `a.localeCompare(b)`.

---

This could be made more efficient by pulling the regex out of the comparison function so it is just created once and reused on every comparison:

```
var nRegex = /\d/g;
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.replace(nRegex, "");
    b = b.replace(nRegex, "");
    return b.localeCompare(a);        
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I wanted =)

Comment: Edit, never mind I check the function spec's instead.